# How to make UIBarButtonItem text visible in UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uipickerview, uidatepicker

Does anyone faced the problem that UIBarButtonItem text in UIToolbar(that is called in UIDatePicker) is not visible until you click on this UIBarButtonItem? What could cause this problem?

[Here you can not see the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoe6W.png)

[But when you click on the screen where it is supposed to be you can see that it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES8kp.jpg)

I tried everything, but the problem is still relevant for each of UIPickerView (including UIDatePicker)

Here is my implementation:

```
@objc func createDatePicker() {
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        //ToolBar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneDatePicker));
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));
        // I've tried to change color of the label, but it didn't help
        //toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.black
        toolbar.setItems([cancelButton,spaceButton,doneButton], animated: false)


        dateTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        dateTextfield.inputView = datePicker
    }
```

Using this code, these buttons are not visible, but when you click on a place where these buttons are supposed to be, text of the clicked button appears.
But is there any way to do it visible all the time? What could be the reason of such a behaviour?

I am a new one in ios. So I will really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Here I am adding DatePicker in textfield begin editing.

```
func openDatePickerForTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    //move view if
    moveViewYPositionForDatePicker()
    let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = .date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    addKeyboardToolBar(onTextfield: sender, onPicker: datePickerView)
}

//MARK:- Add done button on Picker View
func addKeyboardToolBar(onTextfield textField : UITextField, onPicker pickerView : UIDatePicker) {
    let keyboardToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(pickerView.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(25)))
    keyboardToolBar.sizeToFit()
    keyboardToolBar.barStyle = .black
    textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar
    let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonPressed))
    keyboardToolBar.items = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil), nextButton]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case(
Maybe it is some settings for the app? theme settings etc?